# Why Is there an Error for my Test Code but not When I visit the Page Manually?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, integration-testing, runtime-error

I have a site based on the [Rails Tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book). I added a boolean property to my User model called "show_extras" and added a checkbox for it to the User Profile page. My tests now fail when they reach code that mentions the "show_extras" property, such as the Edit User page. When I visit the page manually, I don't get any error. What is wrong? (I tried resetting things, but that didn't help.)

This is one of the lines of code (on the edit page) that causes an error:

```
<%= f.check_box :show_extras %>
```

This is the error message:

> AuthenticationPages signin page for non-signed-in try visit protected
>    page after signin should render right page
>         Failure/Error: click_button "Sign in"
>         ActionView::Template::Error:
>           undefined method `show_extras' for #User:0...
>         # ./app/views/users/edit.html.erb...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be happening because the test database doesn't have `show_extras` column in the User table currently, while the development database does.

Did you do `rake db:test:prepare` recently? You might have to run that in order to create the new columns in the database.

Answer (score 2):

Just a follow up addition, you can create an alias in your `.bashrc` and preparing the test database will be done automatically:

```
# ~/.bashrc

alias migrate='rake db:migrate && rake db:test:prepare'
```

Now when you are ready to migrate the database, just run `migrate` and everything is taken care of. No more 30 minutes trying to figure out why your tests are not passing....

Comment: @garbagecollection glad to help. I wish it was an original idea, but I found it in a book a couple of years ago. Though I cant remember which one.